# Fixing dependency for Google API task-android-sample

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to compile and run the task-android-sample code from Google's API website.  I couldn't get it to work with Maven so I ended up downloading all the jar files.  Below are the steps I did:

1) Import the downloaded task-android-sample project into Eclipse

2) Add google-api-java-client-1.4.1-beta.zip jar files to my project (Build path, add external jars)

3) Download Task API jar file and import to my project:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Tasks_API

4) Check off all the import jar files in the Order/Export section of Build Path

5) Clean Project

6) Run Project.

I get the following errors:
- ClientCredentials cannot be resolved into a variable
- The import com.google.api.services.samples.shared cannot be resolved.

I searched in the Google API website and couldn't find where to download the file from.  I did a Google search and couldn't find a jar file that would contain the class.  Can someone help me to solve this dependency issue?

UPDATE: 9/20/11 **
I followed the instructions specified here:
http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html

The "mvn sources:jar install" command does not give me any error, but when I run "mvn compile" I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] <My_Path>/google-api-java-client.samples/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java:    [221,53] package R does not exist
[ERROR] <My_Path>/google-api-java-client.samples/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java: [225,20] package R does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors 

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.707s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 20 23:15:09 CDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project tasks-android-sample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] <My_Path>/google-api-java-client.samples/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java:[221,53] package R does not exist
[ERROR] <My_Path>/google-api-java-client.samples/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java: [225,20] package R does not exist
```

I already verify my maven installation as per Apache's instructions, so not sure why I can't still compile this properly.

Comment: Where does this error occur, in the JAR file, in your code file where you try to use the API or in the Eclipse console?

Comment: Error occurs in Eclipse once I setup everything (i.e. add all API jar files into my imported task-android-sample) and try to run the application (Run/Run in drop down menu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed. Please try it again.  Thanks for reporting the problem.  Instructions are here:

http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default

Comment: I finally came back to this and tried it out. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 1):

The above issue has been reported to google-api-java-client:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=300