# Fixing Out of Memory Error for Google API task-android-sample

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run the Task-Android-sample given at [Google Api Java Client](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default)

I have eclipse, Java 6 and Android plugin installed but no maven, So what i have done is

1. I copied the TasksSample.java file and pasted it my Starting Activity file.
2. Add google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta jar files to my project (Build path, add external jars)
3. Download Task API jar file from "[Task Jar file](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Tasks_API)" and and imported to my project
4. Tried many times but wasn't successful in opening ClientCredentials.java so i removed it and replaced ClientCredentials.KEY by the key i have got from [Google Api Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)
5. Created a virtual device with 512MB memory for "Google API's by Google Inc., Android API 8"
6. Yet again and again it give me same error "Out of Memory" Error and eclipse is shutting down.

Can any body help me out? I tried all help provided from this question [StackOverflow Question on Task-Sample Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457521/fixing-dependency-for-google-api-task-android-sample/8100481#8100481) but was not able to eradicate Error. I have trying for past 2 days to run a sample program which uses any one of google Api however i haven't got the success till now. Please help me out.

A Dialog pops up and Title="Problem Occurred" Content-"Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit exceeded". It has 2 buttons OK and <

1. Title-Android Launch Content-Your Project contains error(s), please fix them before running you application
2. Title-Internal Error Content-While showing the internal error you are recommended to exit the workbench.

Log -
[2012-01-21 14:24:13 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2012-01-21 14:24:13 - google_api_ex] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded

.log file output

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-01-21 14:21:25.945
!MESSAGE Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:370)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.Rops.ropFor(Rops.java:1210)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:478)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:692)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:763)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:95)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:684)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:639)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:252)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:256)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:483)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:745)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:634)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-01-21 14:24:29.723
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openError(MessageDialog.java:431)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$4.run(AdtPlugin.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.InternalErrorDialog.open(InternalErrorDialog.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.openQuestionDialog(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handleException(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler$1.runInUIThread(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PRINTCLIENT(Composite.java:1618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4590)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar.callWindowProc(ProgressBar.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2531)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler$1.run(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openError(MessageDialog.java:431)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$4.run(AdtPlugin.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-01-21 14:24:29.749
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Periodic workspace save.".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(DataDeltaNode.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(NoDataDeltaNode.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(NoDataDeltaNode.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(NoDataDeltaNode.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(NoDataDeltaNode.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(NoDataDeltaNode.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(NoDataDeltaNode.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(DataDeltaNode.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.simplifyWithParent(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.simplifyWithParent(DataDeltaNode.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.simplify(DeltaDataTree.java:945)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.forwardDeltaWith(DeltaDataTree.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.forwardDeltaWith(DeltaDataTree.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeWriter.writeDelta(ElementTreeWriter.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.snapTree(SaveManager.java:1452)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1162)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.DelayedSnapshotJob.run(DelayedSnapshotJob.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Is Eclipse or your program throwing the "Out Of Memory" error? Can you post a stacktrace, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, Actually i was adding up all the jar files that i got from google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip file and that some how increased the size the project, so by reducing them to minimum required, i was able to run the project. Still it is not clear it why this problem occurred with Android Project as  i have been working in my office on Java Web Application project and it has more than 100 jars attached with it but i had never got this error in running that project on eclipse. Then why on Android?